# How to combine these 2 IE conditional statements into one?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mobile, html5boilerplate

For a Mobile first responsive site. I'm combining [HTML5 Boiler plate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and [Mobile Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/)

I have one little question.

How to combine these 2 IE conditional statements into one?

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this one:

```
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|((gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile))]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

As far I know it should be possible to add another pair of brackets and combine them with an  `or` operator.

By the way I don't think that it is a good idea to manipulate in this way the `html` tag.

Answer (score 2):

See for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment for details.

You can combine logical expressions with ands and ors (`&` and `|` respectively).

So try:

```
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I love it when someone beats me to the punch when I would have given an erroneous answer. I was sure this was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if gt IE 8 |((gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile))]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx